# function not displaying an output in R

Tags: r, function

I know the header sounds confusing but thats what I have now:

```
ticker<-c("AAPL","TSLA")
quantmod::getQuote(ticker)$'Trade Time'

[1] "2022-12-21 16:00:04 EST" "2022-12-21 16:00:04 EST"
```

The above line works normally, however, when I turn this line to a function like below:

```
trade_time<-function(ticker){
  quantmod::getQuote(ticker)$'Trade Time'
  trade_time
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
> trade_time(ticker)
function(ticker){
  quantmod::getQuote(ticker)$'Trade Time'
  trade_time
}
```

May I know what is the function missing in order to show the output? Many thanks.

Comment: Just remove the `trade_time` at the end.  i.e. you just need `quantmod::getQuote(ticker)$'Trade Time'`

Comment: may I ask when am I required to put the return variable after the function is written,  or in the case, where I am not required to put the return variable? Thanks Akrun

Comment: In `R`, the value of the last statement in the function in returned by default unless you have a `return` before that line.   i.e suppose you have a function `f1 <- function(x) {if(x > 10) {return("Yes"); "hello"}; return("Not TRUE")}`  The default case is returned if it is not TRUE i.e. `f1(5)
[1] "Not TRUE"` and the other case `f1(11)#
[1] "Yes"`  Note that here we provided `return`, so the last statement with "hello" is not returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trade_time` is the function created.  We need to return the value i.e.

```
trade_time<-function(ticker){
   quantmod::getQuote(ticker)$'Trade Time'
}
```

-testing

```
trade_time(ticker)
[1] "2022-12-21 16:00:04 EST" "2022-12-21 16:00:04 EST"
```

---

Just to show an example how the `return` works i.e. in `R`, the last statement output is `return`ed even if we don't explicitly mention `return`.  But, we can use `return` before the last line as well e.g. to `print` or do something else

```
f1 <- function(x) 
   {
     if(x > 10) 
         {
          return("Yes")
         "hello"
       }
  return("Not TRUE")
}
```

In this function, we only have an `if` case and a default `return` if the expression is not satisfied.  Also, note that the "hello" is the last statement within the `if` block, but it is not returned as there is an explicit `return` before that line

```
> f1(5)
[1] "Not TRUE"
> f1(11)
[1] "Yes"
```